# Cleaning dataframe columns for classification

Tags: python, pandas, knn

I'm trying to remove all the irrelevant information from one of my columns in my dataframe but have no idea how to do it. I import the data from a CSV file straight to my dataframe.

```
0       [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam...

1       [{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "...
2       [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam...


4798    [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 80, "nam...
4799    [{"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"}, {"id": 10749, "...
4800    [{"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"}, {"id": 18, "nam...
```

I would like to just have the genre e.g action, comedy, adventure. If anyone could help me or send me in the correct direction to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
 ID    Name

 1     Action
 2     Comedy
 3     Adventure




 def printOneCol():
       my_sheet = 'Sheet1'
       file_name = 'C:/Users/you/Desktop/test.xlsx'
       df = pd.read_excel(file_name,sheet_name=my_sheet, usecols='B:B')
       print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

This is via using excel. You can specify which column with `usecols='B:B'`

Hope it helps out.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply functions to columns using `apply` method.

```
df[column_name] = df[column_name].apply(lambda x: x if x in ['action', 'comedy', 'adventure'] else None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have loaded the data into a dataframe `df` and it has a column called `name` which represents the genre. You may then do the following to filter the required genres -

```
req_genres = ['action', 'comedy', 'adventure']
filtered_df = df[df['name'].isin(req_genres)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

The above will give you only rows where the genre is 'action', 'comedy' or 'adventure'.